# How can i sort HashMap<String,Int> order by their values in Kotlin?

Tags: list, sorting, kotlin, hashmap, treemap

Here is my example, how can i do that in Kotlin?

```
var hashMapForTry = HashMap<String,Int>()

hashMapForTry.put("Hi",5)
hashMapForTry.put("What",7)
hashMapForTry.put("How",2)
hashMapForTry.put("Go",1)
hashMapForTry.put("Ford",9)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot sort a `HashMap` because it doesn't guarantee that its entries will be iterated in any particular order. You can, however, arrange the items into a `LinkedHashMap` which keeps the insertion order:

```
    val resultMap = hashMapForTry.entries.sortedBy { it.value }.associate { it.toPair() }

    println(resultMap)
```

Here the entries of `hashMapForTry` are sorted by entry value, then [`associate`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate.html) function converts the list of entries into a map that preserves the order of entries from that list.

The result type of this function is `Map<String, Int>`. If you need to mutate the result further, you can use [`associateTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate-to.html) function and specify an empty destination `LinkedHashMap` as a parameter:

```
....associateTo(LinkedHashMap()) { ... }
```

Comment: Or a `TreeMap` which uses a comparator to determine the order

Comment: @AjahnCharles `TreeMap` uses a comparator to compare *keys*, it cannot be used to order them based on the corresponding *values*.